# Cross Bird Puzzle

Tags: knowledge, steganography, crosswords

```
I've been wanting to do another crossword puzzle. But not one
that is too simple, one that is a little hard. Equal parts hard to
simple, you know what I mean? Not a cryptic-type format, those
have been so done, and not a Regex-type crossword, also. I want to
do one that is different, but the same, yet demanding, and yet not.
"Is it even possible, at this stage?" I asked. Certainly!
Then I told myself, of course it is. I believe in constant hope.
Maybe I should shut up and just start at this point.
```

---

[image]

---

## Directions:

**Across:**

```
4: {✔,07} Force that moves a compass needle  
5: {✔,02} I'm a Capricorn, but my sister is a different line  
7: {,01} HBO show that has same name as '70s movie  
8: {✔,04} The opposite of "Confederates" during US Civil War  
10:{✔,10} The Star that Doesn't Move
```

**Down:**

```
1: {,03} Really bright star that sometimes shows up at dawn?
2: {,05} The closest ocean if you live in Kinshasa, DRC  
3: {✔,08} Direct (a book, etc.) toward interests of a particular group  
6: {✔,09} The closest ocean if you live in Indianapolis, Indiana, US  
7: {✔,06} Thin crescent at dusk  
9: {✔,11} Sunday after full moon that's after the March equinox, usually
```

---

**So the question (of course!) is:**

> What is my favorite kind of **Bird**?

---

#### Hint #1:

> This puzzle has 5 distinct, significant elements:
>
>  1. Opening inane commentary (in code block form)
>  2. Graphic puzzle grid
>  3. Instruction
>  4. Clues for Across and Down
>  5. Puzzle Question

#### Hint #2:

> Each of the Clue/Answer pairs is indicative of something. (See Instructions)

#### Hint #3:

> The clues have been discovered, and the [puzzle has been filled out correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzyO8.png). What's left to discover is:
> a) significance of numbers/symbols in clues,
> b) significance of instruction, and
> c) significance of the opening remarks.

#### Hint #4:

> I've looked *everywhere* for another hint to give: I looked North, East, West... Maybe I should just give up **at this point**.

Comment: I am not at all sure I understand any of what's going on here, but is it possible that 7d should say 07 instead of 06? (Note: I haven't made _the most obvious_ class of error here.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Um, why? I double checked for the 4th time (octuple-checked?). All numbers, etc. are correct.

Comment: I didn't want to say why for fear of spoilers. I'll explain later if you remind me. Thanks for checking!

Comment: Ugh, all my attempts at extraction are failing and I should really be getting some work done :-).

Comment: Where can I send you a 80% solved image to cross verify?

Comment: Does "you" mean me or Chowzen? (I have what I believe are all the clue answers but one, and am more or less certain about all but one of those. But of course unlike Chowzen I could be wrong about any of them.)

Comment: No, sorry, I was talking about the "you" in Manoj's comment. The "you" in the clues is fine.

Comment: i was making a crossword and wanted to add a background as you did. how did you make the image? thanks

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I used [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/). It's a free image manipulation program. You can  get help using it with [their tutorials](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/) and , of course, [right here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gimp).

Comment: @Chowzen Is there any significance in the capitalization in clue no. 10 (Star that Doesn't Move) and the question mark at the end of clue no. 1?

Comment: @Levieux No. I'll elaborate in a third clue.

Comment: Hmm, for part b), is rot13(qverpgvbaf) the instruction you're talking about? At first, I assumed the instruction was simply the clues, but I now see in your first hint that these are actually separate elements. Concerning part a) and c), as Legorhin pointed out, perhaps the opening lines must be split up in 11 parts and be combined with the crossword answers in the indicated order. E.g., rot13(Pbzovavat JRFGJBEYQ jvgu gur svefg fragrapr zvtug yrnq gb gur yrggre Y, fvapr vg'f gur bayl yrggre abg pbagnvarq va gung fragrapr. Pbagvahvat va guvf jnl, jr zvtug bognva gur yrggref PIX???BNER)

Comment: @Chowzen Can you confirm that rot13(qverpgvbaf) is actually the instruction you're alluding to in your hints? And would you perhaps be so kind as to indicate whether or not the other part of my previous comment is in any way going in the right direction?

Comment: @Levieux Yes to the instruction being rot13"qverpgvbaf." The opening doesn't actually get split up into 11 parts, though. it **does** contain the bird-answer. The answer will have 8 letters (one for each ✔ in the clues).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Legorhin [solved the crossword clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89690/cross-bird-puzzle/89704#89704) already.  Here's how to find the favorite bird:

> The commentary says to "start at this point", so you start at the period after the word "point".  Then, use the crossword answers in the order of the number after the checkmark/not-sign, to move one letter at a time in a direction alluded to by the answer (see below).  As you move through the letters, keep the letters with the check marks and ignore the letters with the "not" symbols, and you get:
>
>  1. West (Westworld) = t
>  2. North (Tropic of Cancer is in the north) = **c**
>  3. East (Venus is the "eastern star") = o
>  4. North (Yankees were the north in the civil war) = **a**
>  5. West (Atlantic is west of Kinshasa) = t
>  6. West (Waxing moon appears in the west) = **r**
>  7. North (Magnetic north) = **d**
>  8. East (Orient is the far east) = **i**
>  9. East (Atlantic is east of Indiana) = **n**
>  10. North (Polaris is the north star) = **a**
>  11. East (Easter) = **l**
>
>  This spells out **cardinal**, the favorite bird.  This fits the theme because the four cardinal directions are used to find the solution.

Comment: Nice work :) You should probably mention the other meaning of the bird's name since it is so appropriate (and thus deliberate) here!

Comment: Correct on all counts! I added Legorhin's answer as a link.

Answer (score 8):

taking a stab at it:

> [The Kea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kea)

Reasoning:

> [image: WANING->WAXING]
>  take the 1st letter of the solution marked 01, 2nd of 02 solution etc... (mod length)
>  WANKNGIRALE
>  remove the letters from  solutions
>  AKGIRALE
>  reorder: LARGE KIA
>  Kea is a large species of parrot which is pronounced "kia"

Comment: Ya know, I used to drive a [Kia Sephia](https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FkTtaTNEtfXs%2Fhqdefault.jpg&f=1&nofb=1). :)  +1 for finding this, very creative! But... sorry, no. My favorite bird is a *very* well known one.

Comment: Your answers are right *except* for 7 Down (check Dusk).

Comment: I think you should replace that first N with an X in 7D...

Comment: @El-Guest WANIXG? ;)

Comment: @LeppyR64 absolutely gottem haha! ...on a more serious note, still trying to figure out how the one letter difference means anything in terms of finding the answer....

Comment: @El-Guest I suspect the missing detail is the text in the commentary at the top. (And a wild hint appears)

Comment: if its really waxing vs waning thats a bad clue

Comment: @Legorhin one is visible at dusk, and the other is not

Comment: ok i wasn't aware of that property, though it only mattered on the position of the sun relative to the moon. Updated the image to reflect the correct solution, but it doesn't affect my incorrect bird so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. If this actually matters to the solution an X must be used.

Comment: Some of the answers share their first 3 letters with common bird names: rot 13(jnkvat -> jnkjvat, pnapre -> pnanel, bevrag -> bevbyr, zntargvp -> zntcvr) coincidence or not?

Comment: Maybe. There are also 11 sentence ending symbols in the rambling at the beginning, so that probably has something to do with the actual solution too.